# How to create a SSL certificate and secure connection on localhost?

Tags: php, magento, ssl, certificate

So obviously I'm new around network security and I have this task to finish but I'm stuck for a while now.
I have to create a SSL connection for my localhost (I'm using xampp/apache as a server) where I have to establish a secure connection for my page (an eCommerce page using Magento).

So far, I understood that I need a certificate but whenever I try to get one the hostname doesn't allow 'localhost' as a hostname? So what am I missing? Or what should I fill in as a hostname? I don't understand..
I have a x509 certificate, would it work to secure the connection?

Comment: Unfortunately your question suggests that you did not properly look for [existing questions about this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+localhost+certificate). Since your question only shows a vague problem description I've marked it as a duplicate of some highly voted question about this topic. If you feel that this is not a duplicate please show how your question differs from this and other questions about this topic and add enough details on what you've tried and how you failed so that one can actually help.

Comment: could you please specify what should be put to the hostname.?? im using localhost and it doesnt work that way...

Comment: for example when i try to create a certificate on Lets Encrypt it doesnt accept localhost as hostname? I dont understand what should be put there? or can u just put whatever domain name and use the same certificate for ssl for localhost?

Comment: To cite myself: *If you feel that this is not a duplicate please __show how your question differs from this and other questions__ about this topic and __add enough details on what you've tried and how you failed__ so that one can actually help.* . Apart form that: you are not the only owner of  "localhost" so you cannot get a certificate for it from a public CA like Let's Encrypt.

Comment: look.. i created a site using magento on local host. what i am asking is
WHAT SHOULD I PUT ON DOMAIN NAME to get a certificate so that https:// localhost WORKS?!! httpS*